# Proving subset of vector space is closed under scalar multiplication

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous functions $f$ defined on $[0,1]$. Let $S$ be a subset of these functions such that $\int_0^1 f(x) = \int_0^1x f(x)$.

To prove it is closed under scalar multiplication, I've done the following:

$$\int_0^1rf(x) = r\int_0^1xf(x)= \int_0^1rx f(x).$$

Basically, it's just moving the scalar $r$ around. I'm not sure how to prove $S$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Sometimes it's so simple it feels like it can't be right, I know.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why $\int_0^1rf(x) = r\int_0^1xf(x)= \int_0^1rx f(x)$ shows that $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Because $f(x)$ being in the space implies that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) = \int_0^{1}xf(x)$. So if $f(x)$ satisfies the above condition, so will $rf(x)$, hence $rf(x)$ is in the space if $f(x)$ is, which is just another way of saying that the space is closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course what you've written is correct, but it could be made clearer in my opinion. For example, the placement of $r$ in the final expression could be better.

Here's the sequence of equalities I would use:

$$\int_0^1 rf(x)dx = r\int_0^1f(x)dx = r\int_0^1xf(x)dx = \int_0^1xrf(x)dx.$$

First of all, this shows very clearly that $\int_0^1rf(x)dx = \int_0^1xrf(x)dx$ which is what you need to demonstrate that $rf(x)$ belongs to $S$. Furthermore, the second expression doesn't appear in your calculations as you perform two steps at once; when writing out manipulations in a formal proof which seem obvious, you should try to avoid this as you may be missing an important point. Finally, I could have put in a penultimate equality involving the expression $\int_0^1rxf(x)dx$, but I'm not sure it adds anything to the argument.

The fact that I have used $dx$ and you haven't is not part of my suggestion. If you don't use $dx$ in the course, you don't have to use it.